# What is the difference between these two SQL queries calculating difference in seconds?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, timestamp, date-difference

**Query 1 :** `SELECT( CAST( DATEATTRIBUTE2 AS DATE) - CAST(DATEATTRIBUTE1 AS DATE) ) * 86400 AS result FROM A_TABLE;`

**Query 2 :**

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT( day from ( dateattribute2 - dateattribute1) )*86400 +
  EXTRACT( hour from ( dateattribute2 - dateattribute1) )*3600 +
  EXTRACT( minute from ( dateattribute2 - dateattribute1) )*60 +
  EXTRACT( second from ( dateattribute2 - dateattribute1) ) AS result
  FROM A_TABLE;
```

*dateattribute1* and *dateattribute2* are bothe of the type TIMESTAMP.

Both the SQL queries seem to be calculating the difference in seconds. Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: @GurV Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried doing that and found that in some cases they were equal and in some cases they were not.

Comment: While the first query simply calculates a 'day-differnece'  and multiplies it with the 'amount of secons a day' (Since it's **DATE** the actual time of the days is ignored !!!) the second query calculates days to seconds + hours to seconds + minutes to seconds ...

Comment: They may be equal when the `Time`  of `DATEATTRIBUTE2` and `DATEATTRIBUTE1` are the same

Comment: @FelixD. Hi! I was also thinking along the same lines but consider dateattribute1 as 12-02-17 02:40:10.000000000 AM and dateattribute2 as 15-02-17 03:15:10.000000000 AM. The first query gives 261300.0000000000000000000000000000000004 while the second one gives 261300.
Why this difference?

Comment: @FelixD in Oracle, the DATE datatype does store the time along with the date. However, unlike TIMESTAMP, DATE doesn't store fractions of a second.

Comment: @Boneist so that's where the fraction in the above comment comes from ? If so you may post that as an answer :D

Comment: @FelixD. no, the first query is giving the fraction of a second in the first query due to rounding issues in Oracle's internal calculations. It's annoying, but it does sometimes happen.

Comment: @noobCoder - is it true that the difference is always very small? (It should be.) One issue is rounding errors in the first calculation, since the difference (number of days) involves division by 86400. With computers, which work in base 2, it is not possible for (1/3) * 3 to exactly equal 1 (unless you do it in software somehow), because 1/3 does not have a finite representation in base 2. (Just like it doesn't in base 10.) Something to always be aware of - not just in Oracle and SQL, but in IT in general.